# How to avoid a “can never match” error from Dialyzer in a `with` statement that has a match all `else`?

Tags: elixir, typechecking, dialyzer

I have the following code:

```
@spec test_pass(String.t) :: (:failed | {:ok, map()})
def test_pass(pass) do
  db_user = %{password_hash: @hash_for_foo}
  with {:ok, ^db_user} <- Comeonin.Argon2.check_pass(db_user, pass) do
    {:ok, db_user}
  else
    _ -> :failed
  end
end
```

And Dyalizer is giving me the "can never match error":

```
⟨my_file⟩.ex:25: The pattern {'ok', _} can never match the type {'error',<<_:64,_:_*8>>}
```

My Question is, why? I know it can't match, and I actually don't care, that's why I'm using `with` in the first place. All of the non-matching cases are handled in the `else`.

**How can I change my code that `dialyzer` will be satisfied?**

I'm *not* looking for `@dialyzer {:nowarn_function, …}`. I already tried it with a `{:error, _} -> …` expression in the `else` body but no avail.

Erlang/Elixir version (`elixir -v`):

```
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.2] [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [ds:8:8:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Elixir 1.6.1 (compiled with OTP 19)
```

[`Argon.check_pass/2` is external, from `Comeonein`](https://github.com/riverrun/comeonin/blob/v4.1.2/lib/comeonin/base.ex#L119).

I checked `comeonin` out, and ran `mix dialixier` on it and it reported several `no local return` errors.

Comment: What version of elixir are you using?

Comment: updated elixir version output

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Dialyzer is very user unfriendly. Nevertheless, if it reports an error it means that based on the various type specification you have annotated your functions with, accordingly it is seeing a contradiction with your actual usage.

When Dialyzer is complaining about `{'error',<<_:64,_:_*8>>}`, it means that `Argon2.check_pass` has some contradictory type specifications to it, either itself, or either potentially something deeper down. Dialyzer is not very friendly in its ability to point you out exactly where and why contradictions are happening.

As I do not have full access to your code, in order to resolve the issue, at most I can point you out to following a few steps:

1. If `Argon2.check_pass` has an explicit `@spec` annotation, then comment that out and see if Dialyzer still complains.
2. If the complaint is gone, then modify various parts of  `@spec` annotation with `any` until the problem is gone for identification purposes. Accordingly the issue will resolve there or either you need to dig deeper in other functions that `Argon2.check_pass` relies on that may be the cause of the issue.
3. In the case that 1. fails, then copy paste the function defined `Argon2.check_pass` as a private function: `tmp_check_pass` and see how that changes the issue.

4.If need be, you may need to introduce more of these `tmp_...` functions that `Argon2.check_pass` is relying on in order to isolate the root cause of the complaint. Before doing that, first try commenting out all the `@spec` annotations of any of the supporting functions that `Argon2.check_pass` leverages and apply point 1 accordingly.

Eventually, you will arrive at a particular point in your code, where according to the specifications that you have provided to Dialyzer, that some usage of your code violates it being: of type `{'error',<<_:64,_:_*8>>}`

The key thought here is to try to isolate the root cause of the complaint, which Dialyzer regretfully is not too precise at pointing out for you from time to time.

Comment: Ah I forgot to put the `check_pass` function in the question, but a very nice answer. It's actually not mine, [it's from external](https://github.com/riverrun/comeonin/blob/master/lib/comeonin/base.ex#L119) and does not have `@spec` annotations.

Comment: 1. Are you able to reproduce the issue with a minimal repo that loads the external library? 2. If you `git clone` the library itself and do dialyzer on it, does it still report the same issue?

Comment: …I'm letting it run right now, but generating the plts takes some time

Comment: I'll update the question with the info you requested.

Comment: [a minimal gist with the code from above](https://gist.github.com/P-Seebauer/b7144d3fb4a47bc1ee3066cb161a965d)

Comment: Okay, mabe I misunderstood something that you wrote, I moved the `Argon2.check_pass/2` call to a private function which did the same destructuring and gave it an appropriate typing `my_check_pass (User.t, String.t) :: ({:ok, User.t} | {:error, String.t})` and but now I got two "never match" errors, one for the private function and one for the public one… It really seems to me like the error is exactly in the with-clause. I also rewrote it into a `case…` but the same errors occur exactly in the match. Does `dialyzer` not see that there is another clause for that case?

Answer (score 0):

As another question ["Dialyzer is usually never wrong", but I can't figure out how my @spec is incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53302431/dialyzer-is-usually-never-wrong-but-i-cant-figure-out-how-my-spec-is-incorr) said, Dialyzer detected your `Comeonin.Argon2.check_pass()` call will never return OK, so ...

I've no solution yet, just want to clarify the cause.

Comment: No it did not the error was somewhere else… Updated the link to point to the function definition I was actually working with at that time (which you also could have checked, by the way the change to only return `:error` occured in february '19 and my qestion is from '18)