# "Dialyzer is usually never wrong", but I can't figure out how my @spec is incorrect

Tags: elixir, dialyzer

I have some code that is failing dialyzer and I cannot understand why. No matter what I put into the `@spec` at the top of the function, calls to that function return a puzzling dialyzer error. Here is a simplification of the function. As far as I can tell, I have spec'd the function correctly.

```elixir
@spec balances(uuid :: String.t(), retries :: non_neg_integer) ::
        {:ok, list()}
        | {:internal_server_error, String.t(), String.t()}
        | {:internal_server_error, map | list, String.t()}
def balances(uuid, retries \\ 0) do
  url = "/url/for/balances" |> process_url

  case HTTPoison.get(
         url,
         [, {"Content-Type", "application/json"}],
         []
       ) do
    {:ok, %HTTPoison.Response{status_code: 200, body: body}} ->
      response = Poison.decode!(body, as: %{"message" => [%Currency{}]})

      cond response["message"] do
        length(bal) > 0 ->
          {:ok, bal}

        retries >= 1 ->
          {:ok, []}

        true ->
          init(uuid)
          balances(uuid, retries + 1)
      end

    {:error, %HTTPoison.Error{reason: reason}} ->
      Notifier.notify(url, reason, Helpers.line_info(__ENV__))
      {:internal_server_error, reason, url}

    {_, %HTTPoison.Response{body: body} = res} ->
      response = Poison.decode!(body)
      Notifier.notify(url, response, Helpers.line_info(__ENV__))

      {:internal_server_error, response, url}
  end
end
```

My issue is that every call across the codebase to this function is failing if I expect to get anything other than `{:ok, balances}`:

```elixir
  user_balances =
    case balances(uuid) do
      {:ok, user_balances} -> user_balances
      _ -> [] # Dialyzer error here
    end
```

Dialyzer warns that `The variable _ can never match since previous clauses completely covered the type {'ok',[map()]}`. I read this to mean that any call to balances will always return `{:ok, balances}`, but that can't be true as the case statement for `HTTPoison.get` is the last thing evaluated in the function, and it appears to have only three possible results:

- `{:ok, list}`
- `{:internal_server_error, String.t(), String.t()}`
- `{:internal_server_error, map | list, String.t()}`.

I understand that I am likely missing something very obvious but I can't figure out what it is. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank You!

Comment: Do you get the same Dialyzer error if you comment out the calls to `Notifier.notify`?

Comment: @legoscia oddly no I don't. If I go and check that error there's a dialyzer error in that function as well (which I have a PR out for an open source library to fix). So is that the issue? Dialyzer can't analyze the other 2 paths, thus the `{:ok, balances}` branch is the only one it's aware of?

Comment: Exactly. Since Dialyzer thinks that `Notifier.notify` always crashes, it concludes that your function can never actually return `:internal_server_error`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to @legoscia's comment, I investigated the call to `Notifier.notify`, and sure enough there is a dialyzer warning in that function as well (I have PR out to an open source project to fix the spec that is causing the notify function to fail dialyzer). If I modify the notify function such that no warning occurs, sure enough the calls to `balances` no longer produce dialyzer warnings.

tl;dr If dialyzer gives you a warning about a function that doesn't appear to be incorrectly specified, start going through the function calls within your function to find a downstream dialyzer error.

Comment: SO won't let me for a few days, I'll do so then.